# "@" takes as illegal character in jquery ajax Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making an Ajax Call like this

```
var data = { fn: "course_signup", cid: 1249, cemail: emaifield };

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/AjaxHandler",
                        data: data,
                        success: function(data) {

                        },
                        error: function(xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                        },
                        complete: function(data) {

                        }
                    });
```

AS you can see there is an "@" in `cemail`  field and browser throws javascript error there

```
Error: SyntaxError: illegal character
Source Code:
var data = { fn: "course_signup", cid: 1249, cemail: as@asd.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That e-mail address should be a string:

```
var data = { fn: "course_signup", cid: 1249, cemail: "as@asd.com"  };
                                                     ^          ^
```

Any value that is not a Number, Boolean or an Object should be wrapped in quotes. Have a read of the different [Javscript Data Structures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) for how you should structure your data.

Comment: In actual case I am using a dynamic variable for email field. It is a C# string and it will render to email string at execution time. So its not possible for me to insert it inside double quotes.

Comment: You can still wrap it in quotes in C#, e.g. `{ cemail: "<%=this.EmailAddress%>" }` in WebForms, `{ cemail: "@(this.Model.EmailAddress)" }` in MVC.

Comment: RGraham, that will make your code vulnerable to an [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) attack. Use `cemail: "@(Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(this.Model.EmailAddress)))"` for MVC and make sure you JS encode for WebForms. Notifying @Athul too.

Comment: @SilverlightFox The data is being sent *to* the server. As you can see, the data variable is generated outside of the AJAX call so no XSS would occur. Additionally, doesn't razor HTML encode by default?

Comment: However, it is generated _by_ the server so a specially crafted string could break out of the context of the ajax call and exploit the xss flaw.

Comment: Yes it html encodes, but you need js encoding here.

Comment: Yes but (and please do correct me if I'm wrong, because I'm not saying this with absolute confidence) bit won't razor encode quotes to `&quot;` by default?

Comment: No, you couldn't break out of an enclosed string without using a double quote. Since Razor HTML encodes them, this wouldn't be possible

Comment: That's HTML encoding, not JS encoding. If you sent `&quot;` in a JSON string, it would be interpreted as literally that and not the double quote character. Also bear in mind that if the string includes a backslash at the end, your closing quote will be escaped. I find it better to use the correct encoding for the context for two reasons. 1) It will handle anything that is thrown at it and you don't have to do unnecessary decoding/encoding later on (which could be a headache). 2) Security - complexity is the enemy of security so encode correctly and keep it simple.

Comment: PS. Don't forget to include @SilverlightFox in your responses so I get notification. Thanks!

Comment: Any way, I have included jsencode everywhere , that helped me in solving some other issues with illegal characters

Answer (score 2):

Write the email in double quotes:

```
var data = { fn: "course_signup", cid: 1249, cemail: "as@asd.com"  };
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a string of it:

```
var data = { fn: "course_signup", cid: 1249, cemail: "as@asd.com" };
```

Answer (score 2):

This does not have anything to do with jQuery. Your problem is that it is not valid javascript object literal syntax.

Strings have to be wrapped with quotes. (Except keys, if they have a valid variable name).

This is not valid (unless there is a variable called `lol` in scope):

```
var obj = {hey: lol};
```

This is

```
var obj = {hey: "lol"};
```

And if your key is not a valid var name, quote it as well

```
var obj = {"123 hey there": "lol"};
```

Comment: In actual case I am using a dynamic variable for email field. It is a C# string and it will render to email string at execution time. So its not possible for me to insert it inside double quotes.

Comment: Obvioulsy not =)... C# != JS. Just compose in advance your emailField and then put it inside of the `data` obj. Quotes are for literal strings.